# How to know when received push notification in ionic

Tags: android, ios, angular, firebase, ionic-framework

I want to know when a push notification is received in the device (Android and iOS) where my ionic app is installed, but I can't do that because sometimes the app can be closed or in background so I suspect that I need more than only changed my Ionic app code.

The app is in Ionic 5 with Cordova 11 and Angular 11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @E.Maggini Why is wrong my question?

Comment: Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague. Help others reproduce the problem. You should have, at a minimum, code for what you have tried so far. Best case, post a stackblitz or similar which reproduces the problem. But here, there is no code and therefore nothing to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a setInterval method and use getdeliverednoifications method.